# Find the length of the radius of the inscribed circle for a right triangle whose legs measure 6 and 8.

Tags: geometry

I found a solution using trigonometry (law of sines), but trigonometry is introduced much later in the textbook (Elementary Geometry for College Students, 6th ed), so I'd like some hints to get a solution without using trig. Thanks!

Comment: you can simply apply the formula for inradius of a right triangle

Comment: The area $A$ of a triangle is also equal to its (perimeter * the radius on the inscribed circle)/2. Use Pythagoras to find the perimeter. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea that uses just Pythagoras, although this is probably a very standard technique, can't really remember.

Let the triangle be $\triangle ABC$ such that $A$ is the right angle, $AB=8$ and $AC=6$. It's easy to see then that $BC=10$. Now let $O$ be the center of the inscribed triangle and drop perpendiculars from $O$ to the sides of the triangle and let $A',B',C'$ be the base of these perpendiculars on the edges $BC,AC,AB$ respectively. Then $OA'=OB'=OC'$ since $A',B',C'$ are on the inscribed circle.

Look for example at triangles $\triangle BOA'$ and $\triangle BOC'$. They are congruent due to the previous observation and the same is true for the other two pairs of triangles starting at the other vertices. That means that $b:=BA'=BC'$. Similarly set $a:=AB'=AC'$ and $c:=CA'=CB'$. So the perimeter of $\triangle ABC$ will be $2(a+b+c)=6+8+10=24$, so $a+b+c=12$. But $b+c=BC=10$, so $a=2$. Since $AB'OC'$ is a square, the radius of the inscribed circle is also $2$.

You can always do this, so the radius of the inscribed circle will be $\frac{AB+AC-BC}{2}$ when $A$ is a right angle.

Answer (score 0):

[The description of the scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQMPz.png)

Let $x$ = AF, $y$ = BH and $z$ = CG.

CA = $\sqrt{AB^2 + BC^2}$ = $\sqrt{6^2+8^2}$ = 10 (Pyth. thm.)

AF = AG (tangent properties)

FB = BH (tangent properties)

HC = CG (tangent properties)

Thus, we get:

$x$ + $y$ = 6 ...(1)

$y$ + $z$ = 8 ...(2)

$z$ + $x$ = 10 ...(3)

Solving the set of simultaneous equations, we get

$x$ = 4

$y$ = 2

$z$ = 6

Note that DH is perpendicular to BC and AB is perpendicular FD:

Thus, FDBH is a rectangle

FB = DH (properties of rectangle)

So, we get DH = 2, which is the radius of the circle!